# Como hago que un contador salga como objeto en mi json?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql, jpa, spring-boot

**Este es mi controlador que lo llamo de una clase llamada demanda que quiero sacar el contador de los estados por su id**

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
        @RequestMapping(value = "countestado", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<Demanda> listadoxcount() {
        //  String hql = " SELECT  d.Estado_Demanda.nombre ,  con   cat(COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) as total ,'-' ,d.Estado_Demanda.nombre )  FROM Demanda d  group by d.Estado_Demanda.id  ";
            String hql = " SELECT  d.Estado_Demanda.nombre , COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) as total \r\n" + 
                    "FROM Demanda d \r\n" +  
                    "GROUP BY d.Estado_Demanda.id \r\n" + 
                    "HAVING COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) > 4";

            return EntityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList()   ;
                    }
```

***Aca es donde tengo mi clase bean,entity o model como ustedes conocen***

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_demanda")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_personas", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Persona personas;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estado_demanda", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Estado_Demanda Estado_Demanda;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_registro;

    @Column
    private String comentario;

    @Column
    private String descripcion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_entregada_solicitada;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_entrega_comprometida;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_prioridad", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_prioridade tipo_prioridade;

    @Column
    private int urgente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_trama", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_trama tipo_trama;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_capa_red", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_capa_red tipo_capa_red;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_frame_rate", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FrameRate frameRate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_elemento_red_origen", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Elemento_red elemento_origen;

    @Column
    private String interfaz_ip_origen;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_elemento_red_destino", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Elemento_red elemento_destino;

    @Column
    private String interfaz_ip_destino;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_demanda", referencedColumnName = "id_demanda")
    private List<FlujoDemanda> flujoDemandas;

//Getters and Setters de Demanda

//Estado_demanda entidad
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column
private String nombre;

@Column
private int activo;
```

**y aqui es donde tengo el resultado de mi json**

```
[
  [
    "cancelada",
    254
  ],
  [
    "en proceso",
    109
  ],
  [
    "entregada",
    574
  ],
  [
    "registrada",
    476
  ],
  [
    "cerrrado",
    5
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando entity attributes con @Formula

```
@Formula(“COUNT(Estado_Demanda)“)
private int count;

public getCount(){  return count }
```

Comment: Buenas Tardes caballero, umhhh me sale  este error  
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'demanda0_.Estado_Demanda' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Puedes retornar un POJO simple como resultado de una consulta, como se especifica en la [especificacion de JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor)

```
SELECT NEW com.company.PublisherInfo(pub.id, pub.revenue, mag.price)
    FROM Publisher pub JOIN pub.magazines mag WHERE mag.price > 5.00
```

De esta forma tu consulta seria:

```
String hql = " SELECT  NEW com.ejemplo.Contador(d.Estado_Demanda.nombre , COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id))" + 
                " FROM Demanda d " +  
                " GROUP BY d.Estado_Demanda.id " + 
                " HAVING COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) > 4";

return EntityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
```

Teniendo en cuenta que debes crear un constructor con esos parametros para tu POJO.

```
class Contador {
    private String nombre;
    private long cantidad;
    public Contador(String nombre, long cantidad){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Disculpa me sale este error cuando pongo eso org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.athomcorp.entity.Contador]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, long [ SELECT  NEW com.athomcorp.entity.Contador(d.Estado_Demanda.nombre , COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id)) FROM com.athomcorp.entity.Demanda d  GROUP BY d.Estado_Demanda.id  HAVING COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) > 4]

Comment: El error ahi es claro, el resultado de count() es de tipo long